# Should I use an array instead of a random number generator here?

Tags: javascript, java, html, arrays

I am making a memory game using Javascript, HTML, and CSS.

Here is a brief description of the game:

- The program generates a random number, which is shown on
  screen.
- After about 5 seconds, the number disappears and a pop-up box appears on the screen, asking for the user to enter the number he or she just saw.
- If the number matches the one that was previously on screen, then an alert box with the word "Correct" appears. If not, an alert box with the text "Nope. Nice try" appears.

**Here's my problem:**
The alert box says "Nope. Nice try" even when I enter the correct number.

Here is what I've coded thus far:
(Keep in mind that I have yet to any implement setInterval/setTimeout functions. I made the "hide" function manual for convenience.)

JS:

```
/* game level = easy 

numbers from 1-9000 are generated */

function random(a){
    a = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9000 - 1) + 1);
    
    document.getElementById("screen").innerText = a;
}

function getInput(a){
    var input = window.prompt("Enter the number you just saw:");
    
    if(input === a){
        alert("Correct!");
    }
    else{
        alert("Nope. Nice try.");
    }
}

/* hide toggle */

function hide() {
  var x = document.getElementById("screen");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

**My question: Would it be ideal to use an array of numbers from 1-9000 instead?**

With an array, I figure I can do something like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   if(//){
  }
  else{
  }
}
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: You _could_ use an Array, but that's really not efficient here. `===` checks for exact equality (i.e. The value AND the type are checked). But here, you are comparing a number (`a`) with a string (`input`). Convert your input to a number: `if (parseInt(input, 10) === a)` (the `10` here is to make sure your number gets treated in base 10)

Comment: @blex Why don't you provide that as an answer? :)

Comment: @F.Müller Because I'm sure this is a duplicate question, but I was too lazy to search for it ;)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you are treating `a` as a variable with a scope larger than it actually has. `a` is an argument, and its scope doesn't reach beyond the function it is declared in.

In this case, `a` in `random(a)` and `a` in `getInput(a)` are two unrelated entities with a scope that doesn't overlap.

A solution could be to make `a` a global variable and declare it outside of any function, like

```
var a;

function random(){
    a = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9000 - 1) + 1);
    document.getElementById("screen").innerText = a;
}

function getInput(){
    var input = window.prompt("Enter the number you just saw:");
    
    if(input == a){ // make '===' into '==' instead btw
        alert("Correct!");
    }
    else{
        alert("Nope. Nice try.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you receive a String from the user, but you try to compare it to an integer. So lets say that a = 1, and input ='1' , which means they will never be equal.

You should onvert the string to an int and after that do the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
input == a
```

Instead of

```
input === a
```

Math.random returns a number and you're comparing it against a string with type match.

```js
console.log(1 === '1');
console.log(1 == '1');
```